# How to extract certificate from private key text file

Tags: keytool

I have just private key available in a plain text file.  How to import that into keystore (via keytool or some other tool) without the certificate?  Or, is there a way to generate a certificate file w.r.t the given private key file?

I am working on Box service account authentication.  I need to store the private key (downloadable from box as a plain text file containing the key) into my keystore via command line utility.

I have tried just putting private key into keystore via keytool.  It says "unable to load certificates".  I tried to see if we can generate respective certificate from the private key file.  No solution.  I tried just putting in private key without certificate.  Don't know how to do that.

No code required here.  Just importing of private key plain file into keystore.

Comment: You cannot adda private key into a keystore without its respective certificate chain. Whatever the source of the private key was, you should have gotten associated certificate chain.

Comment: Nope, I found the solution.  With just plain text private key file available with us, we can generate a certificate using openssl utility.  Next, with both the certificate and key, I can create PKCS12 file that would get imported into a keystore.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You could add your findings as the answer so others would know how to do it too.